# How to pass a web form function to MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web application using both web form and MVC. I have a function in web form which works fine. Now I want to reference it in MVC controller

This is the function I use in web form:

```
public string getClaimValue()
{
    string claimvalue = null;
    var claimsId = Page.User.Identity as IClaimsIdentity;
    if (claimsId != null)
    {
        var claims = claimsId.Claims;
        foreach (var claim in claims)
        {
            string claimtype = claim.ClaimType.ToString();
            int index = claimtype.IndexOf("MBUN");
            if (index > 0)
            {
                claimvalue = claim.Value;
            }
        }
    }
    return claimvalue;
}
```

But when I put this function under MVC controller, I got red line under 'Page', says 'The name does not exist in current context.'. After removing 'Page', but I didn't the value I expect like in web form.
Need your help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Page is webforms specific object.

replace it with:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity
```

Comment: I tried it before, it doesn't work. Same function, in web form, I can get claimtype equal 'MBUN'. but in MVC, if I use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as claimid, I can't get claimtype 'MBUN'. I can find the different in web form and MVC, Count number in web form is 4,but in MVC is 0. Don't know why.

Comment: Well the Page.User.Identity is just a shortcut for System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.
It seems your webforms application sets the User.Identity object properly (maybe in a Page base class) but it doesn't get set in your MVC controller.

Comment: @howexg9 : Context should be same in both case. Isn't it ?

Comment: I check the function under web form. 'Page' is under System.Web.UI.Page Control.Page. Looks like not comes from Page base class.